# How do you know which ability modifier to use when attacking?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

When you attack you roll a D20 and add modifiers. What exactly is the modifier? Well I know, for example a longbow would be D20+Dex modifier. But how do I know which stat is for which weapon? Like, would a short-sword be strength or dexterity?

Comment: Have you read the Player's handbook, or even the basic rules?

Comment: here's a link to the current (9/2015) version of the [basic rules](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/BasicRules_Playerv3.4.pdf) xanderh mentions

Comment: @xanderh Concur, but that might not be the right sentiment for a new questioner.

Answer (score 36):

Attacks with ranged weapons usually use your DEX modifier.

Attacks with melee weapons usually use your STR modifier.

Weapons with the **finesse** property use either your STR or your DEX modifier -- your choice.

Weapons with the **thrown** property use the same stat as they would when not thrown (that is, usually STR, unless it is also a **finesse** weapon, in which case you choose between STR and DEX)

In all cases, you also add your ***proficiency bonus*** (+2 for a level 1 character, and increasing occasionally as you level up) if you are attacking with a weapon that you are proficient with.  Your character class (and occasionally race or feats) will tell you which types of weapons you are proficient with.

(see PHB p. 149 for a weapon chart that shows which weapons have the **finesse** or **thrown** property. See PHB p. 14 under weapons for which modifier to use)

Comment: @Bash thanks, I updated the answer to change "always" in the first statement to "usually", and removed the "melee" qualifications for the finesse and thrown rules.  I believe this is fully accurate now.

Comment: Great, and thank you for the continued support on a 4-years old answer :) I'll clean the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Strength for melee, most of the time. Except if the weapon has the "finesse" trait. In this case it can be used adding the DEX to hit (and damage!). You can find this information under "Weapon Properties", in the 5E Player's Handbook, page 146.

Answer (score 2):

**Unless stated otherwise:**

- Ranged weapons use Dexterity
- Melee weapons use Strength

Weapons with the finesse property use either Dexterity or Strength (your choice).

Comment: Might want to add: Melee weapons with the 'thrown' property still count as melee weapons. There might be some spells or class features which allow you to use other ability modifiers instead or additionally. (i.e. Paladin's 'Sacred Weapon' *(PHB p.86)*)

Comment: Unfortunately this is just rehashing what's already been covered in other answers and does not add any new information.

Answer (score 0):

To-hit is always strength unless otherwise noted.

It's not intuitive but there is a reason. There are a fixed number of stats and you really don't want too much "ability" to rely on a single stat.

Strength is your attack and athletics stat, dexterity is your physical reaction, dodge and acrobatics stat.

If all your attack and defense relied on one stat then everyone would have 20 of that one stat

It's really just of function of this.

Comment: ''To-hit is always strength unless otherwise noted.'' This answer does not make it clear at all when to use Dex in melee so it is in my opinion not helpful.